# Extract names of deleted files from svn log

Tags: svn, awk, grep

I'd need to extract file names which were deleted between commits. I have this command:

```
svn log -r 1:30 -v | grep ' D ' | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'
```

For this command

```
svn log -r 28:30 -v
```

the output is:

```
r28 | admin | 2017-08-08 10:02:03 +0000 (Út, 08 srp 2017) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   D /smartsvn-linux-9_2_1.tar.gz

Remove test file 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r29 | admin | 2017-08-08 10:02:21 +0000 (Út, 08 srp 2017) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   D /smartsvn-linux-9_2_1 (copy).tar.gz

Remove test file 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r30 | admin | 2017-08-08 10:02:52 +0000 (Út, 08 srp 2017) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   D /testfile.txt

Remove testing file 3
```

For this command:

```
svn log -r 28:30 -v | grep ' D '
```

the output is:

```
   D /smartsvn-linux-9_2_1.tar.gz
   D /smartsvn-linux-9_2_1 (copy).tar.gz
   D /testfile.txt
```

And from that output I want get a output without letter D:

```
   /smartsvn-linux-9_2_1.tar.gz
   /smartsvn-linux-9_2_1 (copy).tar.gz
   /testfile.txt
```

It works almost right but It doesn't work if a file name contains space. I understand why it is happening, but I don't know, how I can solve it. Or is there a better way, how I can do it?

Edit: Meanwhile I solved my problem, but I'm sure that it's rubbish. It works but I'm sure it exists better way. I'd use only grep or egrep, but I coudn't find out if grep or egrep supports groups.

```
svn log -r 1:30 -v | grep ' D ' | egrep '/([a-zA-Z_.0-9\-\(\) -]+)$' -o
```

Comment: What is the output of `svn log -r 1:30 -v` and what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: can you show some sample output of `svn log -r 1:30 -v` and the expected output you need? space is default delimiter, no need to use `-F` and you can filter with `awk`, no need for grep

Comment: @Sundeep I edited my question, I hope that now it is clearer what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to `grep`, you can use `awk` to achieve what `grep` can do.
Use `/ D/` to filter the lines contain `D`

You may use `awk` to print the substring of `$0` start from 6 (which is the start point of your desired pattern)

```
$ svn log -r 28:30 -v | awk '/ D/{print substr($0,6)}'
```

Or you may use `sub(/[^/]*/` to filter `non-/` out:

```
$ svn log -r 28:30 -v | awk '/ D/{sub(/[^\/]*/,"",$0);print $0}'
```

Comment: Thx, it works perfect. I knew it that it would be an easier way.

Comment: Glad it can help. Then maybe accept or vote it up. :)

Comment: Now I noticed you have a mistake in second command. You forgot to escape a literal slash. 
$ svn log -r 28:30 -v | awk '/ D/{sub(/[^\/]*/,"",$0);print $0}'

Comment: The slash between `[ ]` is allowed to not prepend back-slash. The second command works fine here.

Comment: I get this error: awk: line 1: regular expression compile failed (bad class -- [], [^] or [)
[^
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ]
awk: line 1: runaway regular expression /,"",$0);pr ..., If I don't escape "/". If I escape the literal slash "\/" then works fine. I tried on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I'm using GNU Awk 4.0.1 under ubuntu 14.04, maybe it's caused from different awk we used. I'll modify the answer since with escape for the slash is more regular usage.